# Fetch AXIOS on vue but only the first 100

Tags: vue.js, axios

How can I fetch only the first 100 items randomly:

if I use this `<ActorList v-for="actors in list" :key="actors.id" :actors= "actors"/>`
from an api, my browser crashes as its too much data.

im using this under script

```
data() {
return {
list: []
};
},
async mounted() {
const result = await axios.get("https://api.tvmaze.com/people");
console.log(result.data);
this.list = result.data;
},
components: { ActorList }
}
```

Comment: Does the api support returning limited results in the first place?

Comment: welcome. https://codepen.io/judyyy/pen/LLgNer check this. first you need to make you api to accept limit. In your server code. u need a logic to retrieve the first 20 or your limit items. then when the next button clicked, it will get you the next 20 items starting from the the first 21 item. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

send params for pagination in your axios request
i think there is a problem with the API but if it wasnt use computed and filter method to filter your object
somthing like this :
list.filter((a, index) => index < 10)

Answer (score 0):

To get multiple random objects from an `array`, use the [`Array.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method on the array to shuffle the array elements in a random order. Then call the [`Array.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) method on the shuffled array to get `100` random objects.

Live Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    list: [{
      id: 1
    }, {
      id: 2
    }, {
      id: 3
    }, {
      id: 4
    }, {
      id: 5
    }, {
      id: 6
    }, {
      id: 7
    }, {
      id: 8
    }, {
      id: 9
    }, {
      id: 10
    }]
  },
  mounted() {
    this.list = [...this.list].sort(() => 0.5 - Math.random());
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <li v-for="actors in list.slice(0, 5)" :key="actors.id">{{ actors.id }}</li>
</div>
```